# Java - Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, xml, exception, fragment

I already saw this kind of question on the forum, tried a lot of things, but never found a solution to my problem.
I am simply trying to insert a fragment in a main activity and can't get rid of this exception message...
I am coding on Android Studio version 0.9.9. with jdk 1.7

Here is the code for the main activity and the PlaceholderFragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_three);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A Placeholder fragment that contains a simple view
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mTagListAdapter;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
        super();
    }


    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.library_fragment, container, false);

        final TextView answerLabel=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_tag);


        return rootView;

    }

}
```

}

I have to precise that I couldn't override the OnCreateView() method ("method cannot override on the superclass method"), but I saw on the internet that it doesn't matter.

Here are my two xml files:
activity_three.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background_grey">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="81dp" />
```

And library_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="64dp"
android:paddingRight="64dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
tools:context=".PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listview_tag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    />
```

Finally, I got this as log message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   
ComponentInfo{com.eseoteam.android.tagfinderbeta/com.eseoteam.android.tagfinderbeta.MainActivity}:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

Thank you a lot for your help, I am kind of desperate right now...

Answer (score 2):

Here:

> getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new
>   PlaceholderFragment())

You are passing `TextView` to `add` method of FragmentManager.

You need pass View Container id which is able to hold other views like *RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout,...* to `add` method of `FragmentManager`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, I think that's the same idea as the one following and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

container has to be a `ViewGroup`. In  `activity_three.xml` change

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="81dp" />
```

to

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="81dp" />
```